# Typing in textarea not actually changing HTML tag content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I try to type in this textbox, the text I type is not appearing inside the tags of this textarea:
[image]

As you can see, "asd" does not appear inside `<textarea></textarea>`
Why is this?

This is the CSS for the textarea:

```
.active-note-body {
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    color: #333333;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 2.8vh;
    height: 80vh;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

edit: I am stupid

Comment: That's normal...

Comment: it won't show..But when form submit the value will be submitted

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry, should've done my research first

Comment: Html won't change. But u can get textarea value from script or in console by writing  $('.active-note-body').val();

Answer (score 0):

You should check value property of textarea from properties tab too see entered value.